# How to write columns and rows using .map and for loop

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to solve this all day. It's an exercise for a programming course, but I seem unable to solve it. It's pretty beginner but I would still appreciate any help.

http://repl.it/dfl/1

Basically the exercise is this:
create a function called clearBoard()
This function will go through every cell in checkerboard and set that cell's value to null.

we've been using for loops and .map so that's basically the tools we should use to solve this.

I am kind of lost, so I created a function to see how to write on the columns and how to write on the rows. I can't seem to write on both.

I see that my for loop isn't working, and I don't know why. I think I'm doing everything right. The only thing that works is the .map iterator but it doesn't do rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var clearBoard = function (checkerboard) {
    checkerboard.forEach(function (row) {
        row.map(function () {
            return null;
        })
    })
    return checkerBoard;
}
```

But that's probably slower than:

```
var clearBoard2 = function (board) {
    // you can use use i < 8 and j < 8, since checkerboards
    // are always 64 squares
    for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = null;
        }
    }
    // you could also do
    /*
        for (var i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            checkerboard[Math.floor(i/8)][i % 8] = null;
        }
    */
    // since it's the same thing
    return board;
}
```

Here's another way you can do it:

```
var clearBoard3 = function () {
    var board = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        board[i] = Array.apply(null, new Array(8));
    }
    return board;
}
```